# How to configure Hudson to use Maven for dependecies and run JUnit

Tags: maven, junit, continuous-integration, hudson

In Eclipse I have my "Dynamic Web Project" configured with Maven taking care automatically of all my dependencies (once I specify them in `pom.xml`). After implementing my Unit Tests I can simply run them all by right-clicking on project and selecting: `Run As -> JUnit Test`.

How/where can I now configure Hudson so after checkout of all my sources from SVN repository it would automatically invoke(?) Maven (to download all dependencies) and then run all available tests with JUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the default behavior of Hudson (compiling + running tests).
Did you commit on your svn repository the pom.xml file?

Comment: So just create on your hudson instance a job pointing to your svn project repository and you are done.

Comment: It is the default.  In the "goals and options" textbox on the configuration page enter "install", "clean install", "deploy", etc. and the unit test lifecycle will run.  Jenkins should automatically detect the junit output files and generate the appropriate graphs/reports.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a project in Hudson (now Jenkins) in the configuration page you may choose the build phases that Jenkins will run. Then it will run them in the order you specify. There you will have Maven steps where you'll define your goals.

Jenkins itself has to know where to find a Maven installation (or Ant, or any other command that it must run to build). This could be done in the server configuration page.